# How to extend the app timeout in Win 7?

Tags: windows-7, timeout

My program is for rendering an animation clip, but every frame has to be computed before rendered. It seems that if the computation takes seconds, windows starts to recognize my process as "not-responding" and refuses to render anything any more, although in the Task Manager, the process itself appears to switch between "running" and "not-responding" all the time.

I have been searching solutions online for a while. A lot people suggested to delete some registry entries:

HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop\HungAppTimeOut

HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop\WaitToKillAppTimeOut

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\HungAppTimeOut

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WaitToKillAppTimeOut

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WaitToKillServiceTimeOut

But I could not find those entries. And according to the descriptions, all those entries mentioned are about controlling how long the system waits after the user requires to end a process or log off to kill a process or service. So they are not what exactly I want. I guess there must be some threshold to control when the system should start to consider one process as "not responding" and I want to change that threshold into a slightly bigger one.

Thanks for your attention and time, any suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid hanging the UI in the first place by doing your processing/computation in a background thread, rather than on the UI thread. If you're using WinForms or WPF, use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

See here for some BGWorker examples: [WPF Threads: Build More Responsive Apps With The Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328%28printer%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Aphex, does that mean there's no way to solve it in the way that I asked for?

Comment: It's better practice to change your code to be more responsive than to modify an OS environment variable to 'workaround' a relatively common issue (computation done on background threads rather than UI threads). :)

Comment: Of course if you are not the original developer that obviously makes things more difficult...

Comment: I understand that double-buffering and a separation of the UI thread and worker thread is like standard solution for this kind of problem. And I am totally with you when you say it's a better practice. Things are I have a hierarchical simulation system to compute the next frame, so I have to double-buffer everything on each level and right now I don't have that much time to do that. That's why I asked if there is a "workaround" method.

Comment: +1. If your UI regularly goes unresponsive it can affect system-wide responsiveness. For example, any broadcast windows messages will have to wait for a timeout before the thing sending them can continue. (But on top of that, the user should be able to move your app's window while your app is calculating things. Nobody likes windows stuck in place.)

Comment: thanks Leo, I am talking about an experimental demo, not a real product. I just need to show the core algorithm works before the deadline, then I can re-code for it. Of course the rendering is the not part of the algorithm I would like to show. All I would like to ask is if there is a compromise I can make to make it work first, then I will make it better.

Comment: Well, this shouldn't affect the deadline, since it sounds like your algorithm works - just the UI goes unresponsive, because youre doing all your processing on the UI thread and going long periods between handling UI events (the so called 'message pump'). I suppose you _could_ try the old `Application().DoEvents()` chestnut, though that is widely agreed upon to be a _hideous hack_ to get around proper background computation and should never be used in production code.

Comment: Thanks Aphex again for your valuable advice. I got another way to work around it in a more reasonable and elegant way instead of tuning system parameters. I understand that DoEvents() is hanging the thread hence really hideous so never truly considered it before. Anyway, I would like to say I do appreciate your help and will separate the UI and worker after the deadline.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Microstation to build a model, so this is a similar process. About half way through building the model everything freezes up and adds the "application not responding" message to the title.

Disabling the Desktop Window Manager Session Manager worked for me, however in a enterprise environment this is not the best solution, as common users don't have rights to access the services panel.

Answer (score -4):

Try disabling **Desktop Window Manager Session Manager** from services. Worked for me. That also disabled aero theme by the way. Win7 really looks fancy but it has to operate normally.

Comment: This is really not useful at all